# Feeding new data into predict() for multiple regression?

Tags: r, prediction

Assume I have have fit a regression model with multiple predictor variables in R, like in the following toy example:

```
n <- 20
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- rnorm(n)
z <- x + y + rnorm(n)
m <- lm(z ~ x + y + I(y^2))
```

Now I have new date, consisting of x and y values, and I want to predict the corresponding z values:

```
x.new <- rnorm(5)
y.new <- rnorm(5)
```

**Question:** How should I best call predict to apply the fitted model to the new data?

Here are a few things I tried, which do not work:

Attempt 1. Trying to use the `x.new` and `y.new` as the columns of a new data frame:

```
> predict(m, data=data.frame(x=x.new, y=y.new))
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
-0.0157090  1.1667958 -1.3797101  0.1185750  0.7786496  1.7666232 -0.6692865 
         8          9         10         11         12         13         14 
 1.9720532  0.3514206  1.1677019  0.6441418 -2.3010431 -0.3228424 -0.2181511 
        15         16         17         18         19         20 
-0.8883275  0.4549592 -1.0377040  0.1750522 -2.4542843  1.2250101
```

This gave 20 values instead of 5, so cannot be right.

Attempt 2: Maybe `predict` got confused because the `y^2` values were not supplied?  Try to use `model.frame` to provide data in the correct form.

```
> predict(m, model.frame(~ x.new + y.new + I(y.new^2)))
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
-0.0157090  1.1667958 -1.3797101  0.1185750  0.7786496  1.7666232 -0.6692865 
         8          9         10         11         12         13         14 
 1.9720532  0.3514206  1.1677019  0.6441418 -2.3010431 -0.3228424 -0.2181511 
        15         16         17         18         19         20 
-0.8883275  0.4549592 -1.0377040  0.1750522 -2.4542843  1.2250101 
Warning message:
'newdata' had 5 rows but variables found have 20 rows
```

Again, this results in 20 values (plus a warning), so cannot be right.

Comment: `newdata` not `data` for `predict`. Use `predict(m, newdata=data.frame(x=x.new, y=y.new))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter is `newdata` (not `data`) when telling `predict` what to predict for.

```
predict(m, newdata = data.frame(x = x.new, y = y.new))
```

Comment: @Cath - because it was an easy answer and I didn't care or think to search for a duplicate.  They provided a reproducible example so I didn't hate on the question right away so I thought I'd help.

Comment: @Cath Should they have spent a bit more time in the help pages? Probably. But I give people the benefit of the doubt. Who hasn't spent a lot of time scouring the help pages only to not realize the parameter name is slightly different than you thought and you had blinders on to that small detail the entire time you were looking? Should the question be closed? Absolutely. Should there be downvotes? I don't think so but you're free to disagree.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem.